# Delaying the display message in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a button, which shows a message through jQuery on click. Now, the message disappears immediately, and the button comes back again. I want to show the message for some time before displaying the button again. I am new to jQuery, and I tried with some options like `delay()` and `setTimeout()`, but have been unable to get the exact script to make it happen.

Here is my existing code:

```
$('#id1').click(function() {
  $('#id2').html('<p>A code has been sent to your email</p>');
});
```

The .ftl is as below:

```
    <#if !(obj)?has_content>
    <div class="cls" id="id1">
      <a href="/link?email=${email}" id="id2">Send Token</a>
    </div>
   </#if>
```

Can you please advise me on the code I need to make this happen?

Comment: please add your code into the questions it will help us to provide proper solutions.

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj :Added the code what I am using to replace a hyperlink in the UI.

Comment: Is the button a submit button? Is clicking it submitting a form that causes the page to reload?

Comment: @nnnnnn Its not a submit button.

Comment: @Bindumalini KK check the answer

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj :I tried with all the below options.Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div1').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#div2').html('<p>A code has been sent to your email</p>');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it *inside* a setTimeout() function? Referring to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp),

```js
$('#div1').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('#div2').html('<p>A code has been sent to your email</p>');
  }, 3000 // 3000 is equivalent to 3 seconds. It's in MS.
 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the div2 after 3 seconds

cm hx box

```
$('#div1').click(function() { 
    $('#div2').html('<p>A code has been sent to your email</p>');
```

i
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#div2').html();
zv
        }, 3000); 
    });

Comment: I tried this.Still, the button shows the message and just comes back without any visible delay

Comment: I think the button text and the message are the same element, in this case the `a` tag. Try separating them, and show/hide the message only.

Answer (score 0):

check if it is work for you.

```js
$(function() {
$('#div1').click(function() {
$('#div2').show();
$("#div1").hide();
setTimeout(
function() { $("#div2").fadeOut(1500); $("#div1").show(); }, 5000)
})
})
```

```css
.content
{
border: 2px solid Red;
color: #008000;
padding: 10px;
width: 400px;
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:16pt
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="div1" value="Show DIV" />
<div class="content" id="div2" class="" style="display:none;">
Hi, Welcome  Raj
It will disappear in 4 seconds!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to hide the button after clicking and show it after the message is gone.

```
$('#id1').click(function(event) { 
    var $btn = $(this);
    var $msg = $('#id2');

    $msg
        .html('<p>A code has been sent to your email</p>')
        .show(); // or you could use .fadeIn()

    // Remove this line if you don't want to hide the button.
    $btn.hide(); 

    setTimeout(function() {
       $msg.hide().html(''); // or you could use .fadeOut()

       // Remove this line if you did't hide the button above.
       $btn.show();
    }, 3000);

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

If you want an effect when showing and hiding, you can just replace `.show()` and `.hide()` with `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   // Send a callback function, which will be called after the 'fadeOut' animation.
   $msg.fadeOut(400, function() {
       $msg.html('');

       // Remove this line if you did't hide the button above.
       $btn.show();
   }).html('');
}, 3000);
```

---

**Update**

If your html is like this...

```
<div class="cls" id="id1">
  <a href="/link?email=${email}" id="id2">Send Token</a>
</div>
```

then you will not be able to hide `#id1`, because it will hide `#id2` also.

Try something like this...

```
<a href="/link?email=${email}" class="cls" id="id1">Send Token</a>
<div id="id2" style="display: none;" ></div>
```

---

**Update 2**

If your page breaks when trying to implement the above Update, then try this...

```
<div class="cls" id="id1">
  <a href="/link?email=${email}" >Send Token</a>
</div>

<!-- You may have to style this message using css -->
<div id="id2" style="display: none;" ></div>
```

---

**Update 3 (Prevent Page refresh on click)**

See above in the click event I have updated in the last few lines...

```
$('#id1').click(function(event) {
    ... above code bla bla..

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Try this to prevent page refresh. But then you'll have to call your email service manually using `ajax` inside the click event.

```
var emailText = "someones@email.com";

$.ajax({
    url: ("/link?email=" + emailText),
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("Email request sent.");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Some error occurred");
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this.But this breaks the page.Any idea how to separate the message and hyperlink text

Comment: Page break means maybe due to `CSS` problems I guess.. i'll update the answer.. see if that works.

Comment: No luck.I could see the page getting refreshed on click of the link and so it considers it as a new request.Can we avoid refresh?

Comment: ahh yes... in your click event call this.. `event.preventDefault()` `and return false;`. I'll update the answer again.

Comment: This works fine for stopping refresh.But some how in my case, this if not working.Its not calling the backed api provided in the hyperlink.

Comment: hmm.. yes. that's right. Those lines prevent the normal behavior of the `a` tag. Can you try manually calling your service using `ajax `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147811/discussion-between-yeshan-jay-and-bindumalini-kk).

Comment: I am not familiar with Ajax.Can you please guide me how should I pass the URL query string value what I get in the Freemarker page to this Ajax call?.In this case its something like url   /link?email=${email}

Comment: Okay. At the end of my answer I put a small `jquery` `ajax` example. Replace the URL with your one and see if it works

Comment: Can you please show me up how to  show a message message in UI on click of the Anchor link..Its something like Click the link, call Ajax, On sucesss  show a message in UI along with the hyperlink.It means one can click on the link any number of times.

Comment: I made a small example for you here.. [https://jsfiddle.net/81f89huv/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/81f89huv/1/) . Replace the `url` as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your link in Javascript using `window.location.href` and invoke it after 3 sec. Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AchyuthL/aufcrhgk/1/). Let me know if you got expected behavior.